# Can I retrieve a favicon from places.sqlite?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a webextension to manage bookmarks. The `bookmarks` API works fine. Now, I'd like to get a handle of the favicons that are stored in the `moz_favicon` table of the `places.sqlite` database.

So far, no luck, hence questions :

- is it possible at all to access `places.sqlite` from inside a webextension ?
- if yes, how ?

A while back, I made the same thing on Google Chrome. There, accessing the favicons was rather easy thanks to the special url `chrome://favicon/...`
Is there something similar here ?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible at all to access places.sqlite from inside a webextension?

not with firefox atm, you'd have to propose a new api, implement it, test it, get it reviewed by a bunch of people, and maybe after all of that the functionality will be available in firefox.....

good luck!